# Can anyone explain what is happening in the stl function of R?

Tags: time-series, references, seasonality, trend

I am recently working with seasonal-trend decomposition.

Yet I am not that familiar with the approach that R is using.

Can anyone one kindly explain the mechanism of the `stl` function?

**OP questions copied from comments:**

1. In step 2, is $C^{k+1}_v$ again a complete time series (joining all the cycle subseries accordingly)?
2. In step 3, I dont really understand how the filter looks like. What does "the filter consists of a moving average ... followed by another moving average ... followed by another moving average, followed by a loess smoothing" means? Does it means smoothing the series 4 times, each done by the corresponding technique?

Comment: You could read the [article](http://www.wessa.net/download/stl.pdf) by Cleveland the inventor of stl decomposition.

Comment: @forecaster Thanks! This is a very nice article. Thanks for the reference. Yet I have some questions about the procedures. I am a bit confused in the step 2, 3 of the inner loop. In step 2, is $C_v^{k+1}$ again a complete time series (joining all the cycle subseries accordingly)? In step 3, I dont really understand how the filter looks like. What does "the filter consists of a moving average ... followed by another moving average ... followed by another moving average, followed by a loess smoothing" means? Does it means smoothing the series 4 times, each done by the corresponding technique?

Comment: This sounds like a question more about understanding the algorithm than looking for help with how to code R. IMO, it should be considered on topic here.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is in response to the specific questions around steps 2 and 3.

Regarding step 2, yes, $C^{k+1}_v$ is again a complete time series. In fact it extends the original time series (i.e. the one being decomposed) by pre- and post-padding, since the low-pass filter in step 3 needs that padding to avoid truncating the original series.

Regarding step 3, yes, the filter smooths the series four times during any given run of the inner loop.

### If you're feeling adventurous...

You can look at the source code itself. From the R shell, just type

```
$ stl
```

and you will see that R's `stl` function is really just a wrapper around a Fortran subroutine:

```
z <- .Fortran(C_stl, x, n, as.integer(period), as.integer(s.window),
    as.integer(t.window), as.integer(l.window), s.degree,
    t.degree, l.degree, nsjump = as.integer(s.jump), ntjump = as.integer(t.jump),
    nljump = as.integer(l.jump), ni = as.integer(inner),
    no = as.integer(outer), weights = double(n), seasonal = double(n),
    trend = double(n), double((n + 2 * period) * 5))
```

The [STL docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/stl.html) say that the Fortran function lives at "netlib":

- stl: http://www.netlib.org/a/stl
- loess: http://www.netlib.org/a/loess

In `stl` you'll find the `fts` subroutine, which has the moving average calls:

```
subroutine fts(x,n,np,trend,work)

integer n, np
real x(n), trend(n), work(n)

call ma(x,n,np,trend)
call ma(trend,n-np+1,np,work)
call ma(work,n-2*np+2,3,trend)
return
end
```

That way you can get as down-in-the-weeds as you'd like.